# Bean Creation Exception with org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have been using spring boot 1.4.7.RELEASE version with spring security 4.1.0.RELEASE Version very successfully, recently we wanted to upgrade the boot as well security versions to 1.5.9, and the one that comes bundled is 4.2.3, but we are facing this Exception while starting up the project, via the commandline as well as on tomcat. Any help on this would be appreciated.

I have already tried to search similar issues in stack overflow as well as Github Issues database without much success.

> **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean ?>with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in >org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is >org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 's
>   pringSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.getIgnored(Lorg/springfra
>   mework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties;)Ljava/util/List;**
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RE
>   LEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at com.AuthApplication.main(AuthApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
>   **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang
>   .NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.getIgnored(Lorg/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties;)Ljava/util/List;**
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       ... 20 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.getIgnored(Lorg/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityPropertie
>   s;)Ljava/util/List;
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration$IgnoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.java:160) ~[spring-boot-a
>   ctuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration$IgnoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-boot-a
>   ctuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.
>   2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26dd16a8.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$4() ~[spring-security-config-4
>   .2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26dd16a8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f16ff4cb.invoke() ~[spring-security-c
>   onfig-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26dd16a8.springSecurityFilterChain() ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.REL
>   EASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       ... 21 common frames omitted

```
 [INFO] +- org.owasp.encoder:encoder:jar:1.1.1:compile
 [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
 [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
 [INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
 [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
 [INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
 [INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.13:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
 [INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
 [INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
 [INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
 [INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
 [INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
 [INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
 [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
 [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
 [INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
 [INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:test
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.4.2.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     \- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.4.2.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:test
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.8.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:1.2.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
 [INFO] +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.4.4:compile
 [INFO] +- org.zeromq:jeromq:jar:0.3.5:compile
 [INFO] +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.1:compile
 [INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
 [INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.2:compile
 [INFO] +- com.omne:omnesys:jar:1.18.0.0:compile
 [INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
 [INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
 [INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.3:compile
 [INFO] +- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.3.0:compile
 [INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
 [INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
 [INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
 [INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
 [INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
 [INFO] +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.15:compile
 [INFO] |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
 [INFO] +- bsf:bsf:jar:2.4.0:compile
 [INFO] +- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
 [INFO] |     +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
 [INFO] |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0:compile
 [INFO] +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20151123:compile
 [INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.52:compile
 [INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.52:compile
 [INFO] +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
 [INFO] |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
 [INFO] |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.0:compile
 [INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
 [INFO] +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:2.0:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.27-incubating:compile
 [INFO] +- ant-contrib:ant-contrib:jar:1.0b3:compile
 [INFO] +- org.apache.ant:ant-nodeps:jar:1.8.1:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1:compile
 [INFO] |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.1:compile
 [INFO] +- ant:ant-commons-net:jar:1.6.5:compile
 [INFO] +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:1.4.1:compile
 [INFO] |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.3:compile
 [INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.3:compile
 [INFO] |     \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
 [INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.8:compile
 [INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
 [INFO] +- org.springframework.session:spring-session:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
 [INFO] \- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.0:compile
```

Comment: Looks like mix of version problem. Show which version are used.

Comment: @StanislavL used spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE with spring security 4.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: Can you add the maven dependency tree output ?

Comment: @Okoch Added the dependency tree.

Comment: When you open this class `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` from your IDE, is the method `public static List<String> getIgnored(SecurityProperties security)` exist ?

Comment: There is no such method in the SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration, but the point I am trying to understand is why call that itself if it isn't available, have tried upgrading spring-security to 4.1.0, 4.2.3 and 5.0.0 without much success. This happens in the bean Creation part, I tried debugging the same, but it goes to some class for which code isn't shown since its an enhanced class via Spring CGLIB

Comment: It's due to this dependency: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE. The `ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration` class use an older version of `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration`, calling the static method `getIgnored` that doesn't exist in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE`. Updating this dependency to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.9.RELE‌​ASE` should solve your problem

Comment: @Okoch That was invaluable.. Could you please add it as an answer, would love to mark it and close. :) Thanks a ton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to this dependency: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.3.3.RELE‌​ASE`. The `ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration` class use an older version of `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration`, calling the static method `getIgnored` that doesn't exist in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9‌​.RELEASE`. Updating this dependency to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.9.RELE‌​‌​ASE` should solve your problem